# Script with Robocopy on Windows 10 don't work on W7

Tags: batch-file

The following script is working perfectly on Windows 10 but when I try it on Windows 7 the command prompt open and close directly even with a `pause` in the loop.

```
chcp 65001
echo off 

for /f " delims=" %%a in ('type data.csv') do ( 
    Robocopy "T:\XXXXXXXXX" "T:\YYYYYYYY\" %%a
)
```

I have trouble understanding why, Robocopy exist on Windows 7. I also tried to put `pause` in the script but it doesn't work better. Strange.

Could you help me a understand please ?

Comment: If you open the CMD prompt, type name of script and press *Enter*, then the window should stay open and may show the error message. Clicking on the script from Explorer may do as you describe of the window closing. If it displays an error, then you can edit your question.

Comment: Are you sure that the script and data.csv are in the same directory on the Win7 machine?